# Can Webstorm automatically include project js files in html, or merge them into one?

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, merge, webstorm, concatenation

I am using Webstorm a start a angularjs project. I've created a lot of *.js files. I have the include them using the  tag one by one in the html files. whenever I created a new js file, I have to create the script tag.

The things I needed is just like gulp-concat, but without minifying. minified code are hard to debug.

Can anyone help on this? Thanks!

Comment: I think you can concat files with gulp without minifying them

Comment: You can use `gulp-concat` without using `gulp-uglify-js`. Also, if you want to debug minified code, you should be using `gulp-sourcemaps` which makes the minified files easy to debug via the browser's console.

Answer (score 1):

WebStorm doesn't have any built-in functions for combining files... But there are plenty of different tools on the web - plus you can create your own batch files for this.
I can suggest using Grunt grunt-contrib-concat task (https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-concat). It supports merging files. You can run the task using Node.js run configuration, or configure it as a file watcher, or use Grunt console.
Browserify (http://browserify.org/) is one more way to go - it allows using commonjs-style syntax when developing front-end applications, combining the files into a single file for production
Or, try Webpack (https://webpack.github.io/) - it's a modern powerful module bundler